# creating a rectangle with words on it

Tags: java, android, draw, android-drawable, drawrect

so Im trying to draw a rectangle in my java project and for some reason im getting an error and the application shuts down. The error is 03-28 09:05:50.332: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 09:05:50.332: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Process: com.Tripp.thebasics, PID: 4611
03-28 09:05:50.332: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Paint.setColor(int)' on a null object reference

```
package com.Tripp.thebasics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect ourRect = new Rect();

        ourRect.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2 );
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawRect(ourRect, paint);
    }

}
```

and here is the button that goes to that class below

```
public class JokeOfTheDay extends Activity {

    DrawingView v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v = new DrawingView(this);
        setContentView(v);  

    }



}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the paint variable in your constructor before you try to use it. `paint = new Paint();`

Comment: do you know how to shave off the corners of the rectangle? to make it look smoother and better?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two good resources showing how to create custom views and painting.

- http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Also take a look at this example showing how to create a PieChart view:

- http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/CustomView.zip